# php - simpledb - can't get consistent read to work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm using AWS SimpleDB for my site, however if I udpate an attribute with something completely different, searching that property with either the new value or the old value are both returning the same record.

Let's say the 'login' property's current value is 'dev'. I then change that value to 'myvar'.

```
$response = $this->simpledb->select(vsprintf(select * from mydomain where login='%s',array('myvar')),array('ConsistentRead' => 'true'));
# returns the newly updated row

$response = $this->simpledb->select(vsprintf(select * from mydomain where login='%s',array('dev')),array('ConsistentRead' => 'true'));
# returns the same row even though 'login' has changed
```

Am I doing something wrong with the consistent read argument? I have no clue why this is happening. Also, it's been about a half hour and this issue is still happening, I highly doubt it takes AWS that long to propagate changes across servers.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: fyi, forgot to stick in quotes around the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize this at the time, but I was using v1 of the SDK, after updating to V2 all consistency issues were solved.